# gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, crash

Application crashes in presentFrameBuffer (while running in foreground, no interruption occurring).

It's not crashing in the first frame, it draws for a while then it suddenly crashes.

I don't have exact steps to reproduce, but seems related to drawing something specific, still I have no openGL error reported trough the application, including one error check right before the presentFrameBuffer. If I add glFinish before the presentFrameBuffer will crash in the glFinish.

Application is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1) and the above callstack without any other error/log/debug info.

Here is the callstack reported at the crash:

Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread

```
>     #0    0x36871e46 in gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart ()
>     #1    0x36872764 in gpusSubmitDataBuffers ()
>     #2    0x31eae624 in SubmitPacketsIfAny ()
>     #3    0x378a337a in gliPresentViewES ()
>     #4    0x325b6df2 in -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] ()
>     #5    0x0052986e in EAGLContext_presentRenderbuffer(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int) ()
>     #6    0x000e2a48 in -[EAGLView presentFramebuffer] at /svn/src_svn/GG/iphone/Classes/EAGLView.mm:228
>     #7    0x000e4066 in -[GGViewController drawFrame] at /svn/src_svn/GG/iphone/Classes/GGViewController.mm:504
>     #8    0x3809ab0a in __NSFireTimer ()
>     #9    0x39d36856 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
>     #10   0x39d36502 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
>     #11   0x39d35176 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
>     #12   0x39ca823c in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
>     #13   0x39ca80c8 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
>     #14   0x39b9333a in GSEventRunModal ()
>     #15   0x3551b288 in UIApplicationMain ()
>     #16   0x000e1bae in main at /svn/src_svn/GG/iphone/main.m:14
```

Anyone has any clue about this one ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using VAO, this can be caused by the index buffer (element array buffer) referencing vertices beyond the vertex buffer limits (VBO).

Keep in mind that the element array buffer is stored in the VAO, so as long as the VAO is bound, each call to glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER ) **replaces** the index buffer. If you forget to unbind the VAO when you move to your scene's next object you will be altering the VAO of the **previous** call.

More info over here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers

And a debugging tip: oversize your vertex buffers, it might turn this crash into a glitch that you can then inspect with the OpenGL ES frame capture tool of XCode (this requires XCode 4.5 and iOS 6).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem was caused by having glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) for GL_TEXTURE1 but not providing the actual data in the vertex buffer.