# iOS 9 GPU crash: gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm getting a crash periodically with a `gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart`.
The crash is sporadic, and occurs in a complex multi-threaded app.  Sample stack trace below.

It seems to occur (which is rare) when the UI and related handlers are being stressed (think hyperactive user making lots of gestures as quickly as the app and system will allow), with lots of resulting calls to behind-the-scenes and up-front rendering.

Researching `gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart` suggests this may be due to a buffer issue, e.g. a buffer overrun due to an incorect binding or failure to unbind.

[gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196977/gpus-returnguiltyforhardwarerestart-crash)

(not relevant, but I did look: [gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877492/gpus-returnguiltyforhardwarerestart))

My understanding is that a buffer gets corrupted in some way, and the crash happens sometime later when the corrupted buffer is accessed.

I've been through the code and made sure every bound buffer and texture is subsequently unbound to prevent unwanted/unintentional changes by later code; still getting the crash.

I did just come across these, suggesting the possibility of a bug in the OS:

[iOS 9 Beta 4 crash: gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13067?q=gpus_Re) (original poster indicated was fixed in 9 beta 5)

[Re: OpenGLES driver crash in iOS9 Beta2/3](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/35456#35456)

However, I'm currently testing on 9.3.4, so it seems this would be fixed.I've tried making sure all buffers are properly unbound after use, and tried periodic use of `glFlush()`, both without success.

**Does anybody have experience with this, any knowledge on potential sources, means of tracking down causes, or fixes?**

Stack trace:

```
Date/Time:       2016-08-11T20:20:40Z

Launch Time:     2016-08-11T20:15:22Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.3.4 (13G35)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x1
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib           0x0000000191bd9f28 gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart + 12
1   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib           0x0000000191bdaec4 gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 168
2   GLEngine                             0x0000000195e9f1e4 gliPresentViewES_Exec + 172
3   GLEngine                             0x0000000195e9f0fc gliPresentViewES + 80
4   OpenGLES                             0x000000018576bc44 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 68
5   NWFPApp                              0x00000001001ef8fc -[NWFPIOSGLView renderNormalBuffers] (NWFPIOSGLView.mm:543)
6   NWFPApp                              0x00000001001ef814 -[NWFPIOSGLView renderAll] (NWFPIOSGLView.mm:516)
7   NWFPApp                              0x00000001001ee780 -[NWFPIOSGLView doInContext:] (NWFPIOSGLView.mm:135)
8   NWFPApp                              0x00000001001ef770 -[NWFPIOSGLView drawView] (NWFPIOSGLView.mm:494)
9   NWFPApp                              0x0000000100203cc8 -[NWFPGLChoreographer displayLinkEvent:] (NWFPGLChoreographer.m:128)
10  QuartzCore                           0x000000018614022c CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 36
11  QuartzCore                           0x00000001861400e0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 420
12  IOKit                                0x0000000183885e54 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 368
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001835ad030 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
14  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001835c57d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001835c4f0c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 432
16  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001835c2c64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1796
17  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001834ecc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
18  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000184dd4088 GSEventRunModal + 176
19  UIKit                                0x00000001887ce088 UIApplicationMain + 200
20  NWFPApp                              0x00000001002af1a0 main (main.m:30)
21  ???                                  0x000000018308a8b8 0x0 + 0
```

Comment: We had similar issues in our app that uses OpenGLES2.0 heavily. The most probable reason would be triangle Index point to a Vertex out of Bound. The actual reason is, the shader code or the driver is getting a seg fault error like it happens on CPU, to the only change for this to happen is referencing wrong memory address. If you are using VAO, make sure your VAO is unbind after the draw call is made. Sometimes the previous VAO bind might leave a inconsistent state which might also cause this issue.